# Stick NSString[] into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, nsarray

Why can't I stick NSString[] into NSArray? I get the following error "Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'id' is disallowed with ARC"

Here's the code:

```
NSString *s1, *s2;
NSString *cArray[]={s1, s2};
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataArray addObject:cArray];
```

Comment: you can only add instances of NSObject to NSMutableArray.  NSString[] is a C array of NSObjects.

Comment: BTW, use this if you need to initialize an NSArray of objects, `NSArray * array = @[ s1, s2 ];`

Comment: You can also create an NSArray with the items in a C-array like so: `NSArray *dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cArray count:numObjects];` This doesn't insert `cArray` into `dataArray`, it inserts the *objects* in `cArray` into `dataArray`

Comment: @NicholasHart - But he's not creating an NSArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it, because the ownership of `cArray` cannot be transferred.

If it is a local variable, it would disappear as soon as its scope ends, leaving your mutable array with a dangling reference.

Even if it is a global, there would be a problem, because your `NSMutableArray` would not know how to release the C array properly.

Objective C wants to protect you from situations like that as much as possible, providing nice classes such `NSArray` to make your job easier:

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *s1 = @"hello", *s2 = @"world";
// You can choose another constructor as you see fit.
NSArray *cArray = @[s1, s2];
[dataArray addObject:cArray];
```

Comment: Chuck's answer allows an array of arbitrary (and variable) size to be used, creating either an NSArray or NSMutableArray, as desired.

Comment: @HotLicks That's what my comment about "choosing another constructor as one sees fit" is saying, too.

Answer (score 2):

NSArray holds objects. A C array is not an object, so you can't put it in an NSArray. If you want to create an NSArray out of a C array, you can use the `arrayWithObjects:count:` constructor.

Comment: This is the way to go, if you're starting with a C array.  One can create either an NSArray or NSMutableArray, depending on which class is specified in the method call.